# Exception opening Scala-ide (ECLIPSE)

Tags: eclipse-neon, scala-ide

Few days before i have installed eclipse neon.3 for scala IDE, it was fine till yesterday, now i could not able to enter into IDE. The exception i am getting is

An error has occured, see the log file c:/*/*/.log

below the recent log info, Kindly help how to resolve it.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2017-10-03 16:45:14.022
!MESSAGE 
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.JFaceResources.getResources(JFaceResources.java:209)
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.JFaceResources.getResources(JFaceResources.java:227)
    at org.eclipse.ui.part.WorkbenchPart.dispose(WorkbenchPart.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerPart.dispose(PackageExplorerPart.java:476)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.invalidate(CompatibilityPart.java:237)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.destroy(CompatibilityPart.java:403)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:966)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:931)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.disposed(InjectorImpl.java:426)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.Requestor.disposed(Requestor.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.ContextObjectSupplier$ContextInjectionListener.update(ContextObjectSupplier.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.update(TrackableComputationExt.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.handleInvalid(TrackableComputationExt.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.dispose(EclipseContext.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.dispose(EclipseContext.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.dispose(EclipseContext.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.dispose(EclipseContext.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.dispose(EclipseContext.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.osgi.EclipseContextOSGi.dispose(EclipseContextOSGi.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.osgi.EclipseContextOSGi.bundleChanged(EclipseContextOSGi.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:903)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEventPrivileged(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor.publishModuleEvent(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.publishEvent(Module.java:476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStop(Module.java:634)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.stop(Module.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.stop(SystemModule.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$SystemBundle$EquinoxSystemModule$1.run(EquinoxBundle.java:165)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: I have changed the location of workspace, then the error is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

This a known bug in Scala IDE 4.7.0.
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=526699

To resolve it, just upgrade to the latest 4.7.1 (rc-3 today).

Here is the update site for Oxygen:
http://download.scala-ide.org/sdk/lithium/e47/scala212/dev/site